# alternate options for infinite loop

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers, integration

We are running one third party application which uses C#, SQL SERVER. We have created one other application which prints the pass.

Basically it does continuous checking of new entry from third party application in one of the table on remote database. If new entry is present then it prints pass. Accessing network database in such way is not good way and also sometimes application hang.

Instead of continuous loop, I am searching for some other way like: As the new entry comes, it trigger my application for print. Or any other good way to implement.

Comment: Could you show your code as well as that would help us more in answering???

Comment: Timer which will fire some action every `x` ms.

Comment: Your missing a lot of detail here... for a starters how is anyone supposed to know if this third party application can support anything else?

Comment: Are you allowed to make changes to the database? It seems that it wouldn't be unreasonable to have a trigger on the table add message(s) to a service broker queue, and for your code to receive from same queue.

Comment: I agree with @wudzik. We had a server that received new data every second, so I made a `Timer` that tried to get the data from the database every 200 - 500 ms

Comment: In my point of view, Setting time interval to check entries is good way..

Comment: @RahulTripathi:code logic is when application start,in page_load event defined connection string,check for new entry in database,if entry present then print pass..runs well but sometime it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) that can help you in 
listening to the `OnChange` event.

Example from msdn:

```
void Initialization()
{
    // Create a dependency connection.
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, queueName);
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.

    // Create a new SqlCommand object.
    using (SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT ShipperID, CompanyName, Phone FROM dbo.Shippers", 
        connection))
    {

        // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
        SqlDependency dependency=new SqlDependency(command);
        // Maintain the refence in a class member.

        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
        dependency.OnChange+=new
           OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        // Execute the command.
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
}

// Handler method
void OnDependencyChange(object sender, 
   SqlNotificationEventArgs e )
{
  // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
}

void Termination()
{
    // Release the dependency.
    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString, queueName);
}
```

Check it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953.aspx

> If any user subsequently changes the underlying data, Microsoft SQL
>   Server detects that there is a notification pending for such a change,
>   and posts a notification that is processed and forwarded to the client
>   through the underlying SqlConnection that was created by calling
>   SqlDependency.Start. The client listener receives the invalidation
>   message. The client listener then locates the associated SqlDependency
>   object and fires the OnChange event.

Answer (score 0):

let me just sum up the data:

you need to give us more information for a more intelligent help here bu basically you can:

- Use a timer: that way you are not in an infinite loop and you don't check every few ticks the 3rd party. you can be more sophisticated even and make the time interval grow and shrink according to data changes found or not
- if you can change the 3rd party so it'll send events or signal when it has new data then you can use that and register to the events and save a lot of process time
- if you can change the DB add triggers and use them to know then new data come and thus you don't need nothing more then that

Comment: using trigger how can i know new data come

Comment: @RAHUL start by reading about triggers and see and try some examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger / http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch15.htm

Comment: i mean using trigger,i can execute any sql statement(make new entry some other table) but i can't C#.

Comment: @RAHUL i copy Damien_The_Unbeliever comment because it says it all: It seems that it wouldn't be unreasonable to have a trigger on the table add message(s) to a service broker queue, and for your code to receive from same queue